# Latex. Перенос на новую строку внутри equation

Tags: latex

Есть формула

```
\begin{equation*}
        max_X (min_{\vec{Y}} F(X, \vec{Y})) = sup_{X} (inf_{\vec{Y}} F(X, \vec{Y})) = \Gamma_1, \newline
        min_{\vec{Y}} (max_X F(X, \vec{Y})) = inf_{\vec{Y}} (sup_{X} F(X, \vec{Y})) = \Gamma_2        
\end{equation*}
```

Как перенсти на новую строку? `\\` не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equation используется для выражений, которые занимают 1 строку, для многострочных выражений обычно используют окружение multline*, попробуйте его.